# Time complexity between two iterate methods of immutable collection

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

There is an [Immutable.js](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/) with the structural data as collections. Let's take a Map. Also there are methods to work with:

- includes
- filter

Let's consider these data:

```
const data = Map({
  id1: Map({id: 'id1'}),
  id2: Map({id: 'id2'}),
  id100: Map({id: 'id100'}),
});

const ids = List(['id1', 'id100']);
```

And two approaches to iterate this Map:

```
function selectData() {
  return data.filter((item) => ids.includes(item.get("id")));
}
```

---

```
function selectData() {
  let selected = Map();

  ids.forEach((id) => {
    selected = selected.set(id, data.get(id));
  });

  return selected;
}
```

So, the question is: are these two approaches equivalent and have the same time complexity in

- general
- this special case with the data in Map above

From my POV they are not equivalent but time complexity should be the same.

Update: equivalent - do the same, provide the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out, the semantics are slightly different. In the example case they both provide an intersection of the ids, so

```js
> JSON.stringify(s1())
'{"id1":{"id":"id1"},"id100":{"id":"id100"}}'
> JSON.stringify(s2())
'{"id1":{"id":"id1"},"id100":{"id":"id100"}}'
```

However, there are edge cases with the data structure which do not produce like for like results, such as the example you gave in the comment:

```js
const data = Map({
  id1: Map({id: 'id1'}),
  id2: Map({id: 'id1'}),
  id100: Map({id: 'id100'}),
});

const ids = List(['id1', 'id100']);

...

> JSON.stringify(s1())
'{"id1":{"id":"id1"},"id2":{"id":"id1"},"id100":{"id":"id100"}}'
> JSON.stringify(s2())
'{"id1":{"id":"id1"},"id100":{"id":"id100"}}'
```

Note. The above case looks like a bug as the id in the (value) map doesn't match the id of the key; but who knows?

In general

- approach 1 produces 1 item for each item in the top level map (`data`) whose value has an `id` item that is contained in the list.
- approach 2 produces 1 item for each value in the list that has an entry in the top level map (`data`)

As the two approaches differ in terms of lookup in the amp (`data`) -- one goes by the key, the other by the value of `id` in the value map -- if there is an inconsistency in these two values, as per the second example, you will get a difference.

In general you may be better with the second approach as the lookup into the Map will likely be cheaper than lookup into the list if both collections are of similar size. If the collections are of largely different size, you would need to take that into account.

Lookup into the list will be O(N) whereas lookup into the Map [is documented](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map) as `O(log32 N)` (so some kind of wide tree implementation). So for a map M and list L, the cost of apprach 1 would be `O(L * log32 M)` whereas the cost of the second approach would be `O(M * L)`, if `M == L` (or is close), then of course approach 1 wins, *on paper*.

It's almost always best to profile these things, rather than worry about the theoretical time complexity.

Practically, there may be another nice approach that relies on the already sorted nature of the map. If you sort the list first, (`O(L log L)`), then you can just use a sliding window over elements of both to find the intersection...

Comment: Thx! But still: are they do the same? For instance:
var data = Immutable.Map({
  id1: Immutable.Map({id: 'id1'}),
  id2: Immutable.Map({id: 'id1'}), 
  id100: Immutable.Map({id: 'id100'})
});
We would have different results?

Comment: They seem to be both the intersection, which is commutative

Comment: Why? They produces different results:
**1.** First one get output: `id1, id100, id1`
**2.** Second: `id1, id100`

Comment: Ah yep. I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Am i right if i eager to say that two approaches cannot be compare due to some functional differ? As in my case above which is not fully correct but is needed only to show that differ.
P.S. Could you please point links to documentation for time complexity Map and List of Immutable.js? Can't find :(

Comment: Yeah, they are different approaches so a direct comparison needs to be taken with a pinch of salt, but as i said above, they both lean towards providing an intersection of the data. I've added a link to the docs that specify lookup time for the map. I'm assuming the list lookup would be linear. Please mark the question as answered if you are happy.